# How should I make a bug report for the 20.04 server installer?

Tags: server, system-installation, 20.04, bug-reporting

I've discovered a problem with the 20.04 server installer, where it crashes if the BIOS time is incorrect (in my case, because the machine doesn't have a real time clock battery installed, so it always thinks it's 2012 until it can connect to an NTP server).  The issue seems to be a failed certificate validation during install.  Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to copy the crash log off of the machine in question.

I'd like to report this bug, and I might even have the skills to work on it, but I don't really know where or how to do that.  I gather that the server installer consists of a few projects... should I open an issue on the Subiquity github project?

Answer (score 4):

Start with the existing bug reports to make sure yours isn't a duplicate: https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bugs

- If yours is a new bug: Start with https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+filebug
- You will need an Ubuntu One logon to file a new bug report or to subscribe to an existing bug report. If you don't have an Ubuntu One login, you will be prompted to create one. Be sure to use a real e-mail address that you will check.
- Describe exactly how a triager or developer can reproduce the problem on their test system.
- Triagers and developers may as questions via e-mail. If you don't respond, the bug report may be closed.
- If you are capable of testing patches or proposed fixes, please offer. More testing often means a faster and better fix.